# Exibir o nome no input usando autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, autocompletar

O autocomplete está funcionando corretamente, recebo o seguinte json:

```
[{"label":"Jorge Valdivia","value":"16"},{"label":"Vinicius Aquino","value":"15"}]
```

O problema é que quando eu seleciono alguma opção, o input recebe o ID do registro, eu gostaria de fazer com que exiba o nome da pessoa no input.

```
// -------------- Autocomplete --------------
    $('#search_broker').autocomplete({
        source: path + "User/get_brokers",
        minLength: 2,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            broker_name = ui.item.label;
            broker_id = ui.item.value;
            alert('Nome: ' + broker_name);
        }
    });
```

Olha como está ficando:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tem mais algum código além desse?

Comment: Você está falando do código no servidor que retorna o json?

Comment: Não, do javascript do autocomplete

Comment: Tem não, o único JS do autocomplete que estou usando é esse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente fazer assim, inserindo o `label` no input pelo ID dele:

```
$('#search_broker').autocomplete({
   source: path + "User/get_brokers",
   minLength: 2,
   select: function (event, ui) {
      $("#id_do_input").val(ui.item.label);
      return false;
   }
});
```

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado! Eu tinha tentando dessa forma, porém não usei o return false.

Answer (score 0):

Qual autocomplete está usando? Como funciona? Estou fazendo uma busca por nome de usuário num campo input porém retorna só o nome para o value.

Acredito que seja o mesmo que esteja acontecendo com o seu problema que foi sanado.
Ao buscar por USUARIO em um form de cadastro de nova ocorrência, até consigo retornar o usuário corretamente, porém precisava gravar o id dele ao invés do nome.
estou usando a função "autocomplete/jquery.autocomplete.js"

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#userb").autocomplete("completar.php?userb=", { 
            width:200,
            selectFirst: false
        });
    });
```

página completar.php assim:

```
//conecta no banco
include("conecta.php");

$q = $_GET["userb"];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE nome like '%".$q."%'";

$query = mysqli_query($conn,$sql); // or die ("Erro". mysql_query());

while($reg=mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

    echo $reg["id"]."|".$reg["nome"]."\n";

}
```

da forma como esta busco pelo nome e ao seleciona-lo fica o id no input.
se troco o primeiro `$reg['id']` por `reg['nome']` fica o nome no input porem preciso salvar o id no banco.